# Update Joomla Site With FTP From Admin Panel

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

I just set-up a VPS and installed Joomla.  Now I need to update.

When I click on the update button, and I try to do it through FTP I get this error message

> JFTP: :connect: Could not connect to host ' sftp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX ' on port ' 21 '
>   File Checksum Failed

I have valid credentials set in my configuration.php for `$ftp_` host, port, user, pass and root I have set to `public $ftp_root = '/root';`

What do I need to change so that I can update my site?

**Edit**
I can connect using the sftp IP and credentials through FileZilla no issue.

Comment: sftp is at port 22 and ftp is at port 21.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla doesn't support updating thru **SFTP**. Joomla only supports **FTP**.
There is a major difference between **SFTP** and **FTP**.

**FTP** (File Transfer Protocol) is a plain text protocol using 2 separated connections for transferring data. It also doesn't support encryption. Except if you use **FTPS** which is an addition to **FTP**. It needs port 21 (default) and a data port.

**SFTP** (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is based on SSH which is a fully encrypted binary protocol and works completely different. It needs only port 22 (default).

So if you like to update with **FTP** you need to supply **FTP** credentials and not **SFTP** / **SSH** credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "Write files directly"

Comment: Your post has been auto-flagged by the system as being low-quality for its length/content.  Please edit your question to be more generous and educational.  Assume that the OP and thousands of researchers do not possess the knowledge to implement your advice.  Screenshots, step-by-step guidance, and links to online tutorials/documentation are great ways to build a truly valuable answer for researchers.  Thank you.